# Category List Navigation is not working in React App

Tags: reactjs

Hello I'm new to react and trying to create a E commerce website. I'm facing a specific problem in my code.

[image]

As you see from the screen shot above, the navigation of my site.

Whenever I try to click on the Shoes link under Apparel-> Girls, it doesn't redirect to new page.

I don't know where I'm getting it all wrong. Can anyone please guide me on this.
Or give an insight how to proceed.

My code sanbox link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/49rnm480x

My mainCategory Js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import SubMenu from './subMenu';



class Navigation extends Component {

  state = {
    mainCategory: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3030/topCategory')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data.express);
        this.setState({
          mainCategory: res.data.express.catalogGroupView
        })
      })
  }



  render() {

    const { mainCategory } = this.state;
    return mainCategory.map(navList => {
      return (

        <ul className="header">
          <li key={navList.uniqueID}>
            <a className="dropbtn ">{navList.name} </a>
              <ul className="dropdown-content">
                <SubMenu below={navList.catalogGroupView} />
              </ul>


          </li>
        </ul>

      )

    })

  }


}

export default Navigation;
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;//import it here
const app = express();

app.use(cors());



app.get('/PDP', (req, res) => {

   var client = new Client();

   // direct way
   client.get("http://149.129.128.3:3737/search/resources/store/1/productview/byId/12501", (data, response) => {
    res.send({ express: data });
   });
});

app.get('/topCategory', (req, res) => {

    var client = new Client();

    // direct way
    client.get("http://149.129.128.3:3737/search/resources/store/1/categoryview/@top?depthAndLimit=-1,-1,-1,-1", (data, response) => {
     res.send({ express: data });
    });
 });

 app.get('/GirlShoeCategory', (req, res) => {

    var client = new Client();

    // direct way
    client.get("http://149.129.128.3:3737/search/resources/store/1/productview/byCategory/10015", (data, response) => {
     res.send({ express: data });
    });
 });






const port = 3030;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port${port}`));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please provide an example of mainCategory, as you are fetching it from your local machine and therefore it creates an error in your codesandbox.

Comment: Surely I will send you.

Comment: I have the send the mainCategory code and also how I'm using a node server to fetch data.......

Comment: From the screenshot that you posted, it seems that the app is trying to navigate to an object instead of an actual page. Try to look around that.

Comment: There is no need. What you are doing wrong is that you're setting the href to an imported component. You have "href={PLPMenu}". I don't know exactly what links you are trying to set, but you can test it by changing those href to for example "href='abc'}". Hope that helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180345/discussion-between-sajjad-tabreez-and-filipe-valente).